# npm doesn't work for me because of wrong config

Tags: javascript, npm

When I want to use the npm package manager for js we package or project like this command:
`npm start`

It shows me :

```
npm ERR! code E418
npm ERR! 418 Unknown - GET https://repo.huaweicloud.com/repository/npm/yarn

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Amir\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-12-08T13_04_36_000Z-debug.log
```

I think my npm mirror is wrong, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`npm config --global edit`
and
`npm config edit`, it will open the npm config with your default editor.

and then remove the `registry` line for each file to reset it to defaults.

Comment: Thanks, but it still shows that error

Comment: Add your package.json file. Your command is not correct. it should be `npm run start`